# load ajax array data into select2 dropdown format

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, jquery-select2

i have a problem with filling dropdown data from ajax script.
here's my controller:

```
public function ajax_get_kota($idProv='')
{
    $kota = $this->data['namaKota'] = $this->registrasi_model->get_nama_kota($idProv);
    echo json_encode($kota);
}
```

here's my model:

```
public function get_nama_kota($idProv='')
{
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT id_kab, nama FROM kabupaten WHERE id_prov = '.$idProv.' ORDER BY nama ASC');
    return $dropdowns = $query->result();
}
```

and view:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm has-feedback <?php set_validation_style('Kota')?>">        
    <?php echo form_label('Kota / Kabupaten', 'kota', array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-2')) ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <?php
            $atribut_kota = 'class="form-control dropKota"';
            echo form_dropdown('Kota', $namaKota, $values->Kota, $atribut_kota);
            set_validation_icon('Kota');
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php if (form_error('Kota')) : ?>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            <?php echo form_error('Kota', '<span class="help-block">', '</span>');?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropProv").on("change", function(){
                var idProv = $(this).val();
                var baseUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>program/administrasi/registrasi/ajax_get_kota/'+idProv;
                var kota = [];
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl,
                    data: kota,
                    success: function(datas){
                        $(".dropKota").select2({
                             placeholder: "Pilih Kota",
                             data: datas
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

what i'm trying to do here is how to pass this data that im getting from ajax:

> [{"id_kab":"5103","nama":"KAB. BADUNG"},{"id_kab":"5106","nama":"KAB. BANGLI"},{"id_kab":"5108","nama":"KAB. BULELENG"},{"id_kab":"5104","nama":"KAB. GIANYAR"},{"id_kab":"5101","nama":"KAB. JEMBRANA"},{"id_kab":"5107","nama":"KAB. KARANGASEM"},{"id_kab":"5105","nama":"KAB. KLUNGKUNG"},{"id_kab":"5102","nama":"KAB. TABANAN"},{"id_kab":"5171","nama":"KOTA DENPASAR"}]

into the dropdown dropKota. those data is dynamically generated when another dropdown value is changed.

current result:

[image]

select2 requires a specific format so it can be properly displayed in dropdown

> var data = [{ id: 0, text: 'enhancement' } //something like this

how do i do this?

Comment: U have to map the array like this: $data = ArrayHelper::map(Clients::find()->asArray()->all(), 'cid', function($model, $defaultValue) {
                                            return $model['cid'] . " - " . $model['first_name'] . " " . $model['middle_name'] . " " . $model['last_name'];
                                        }
                        );

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
success: function(datas){
    var data = JSON.parse(datas);

    var options = '<select name="dd_name"><option>Select</option>';
    for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
    {
        options += '<option value="'+ data.col_name +'">'+ data.col_id +'</option>';
    }
    options += '</select>';

    $('#div_id').html(options);   // where #div_id is the id of a div in which this drop down is required.
},
```

Comment: this one only give option select, thanks for the respond

Comment: i updated my code, see the current result, i move the select2 JS into the ajax success function, the dropdown is able to load data but it's messed up

Answer (score 1):

U have to do like this :

```
 $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                data: {id: id},
                success: function(data) {
                    var data_array = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(data_array.emp, function(key, value) {
                        $('#Your_drop_down_id').append($('<option>', {
                            value: key,
                            text: value,
                        }));
                    });

                }
            });
```

U have to parse the data(JSON to array) and then use $.each for looping all values.

Comment: i have updated my question, how to format the array data into select2 specific format? thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Change `$.ajax` call as below

```
$.ajax({
    url: baseUrl,
    data: kota,
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(datas){
        var s= document.getElementById('<Element Id>');
        s.eampty();
        $.each(datas, function(index, el) {
            s.options[index]= new Option(index, el);
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

`dataType: "JSON",` will respond output of `ajax` call in `json` format.
Replace **`<Element Id>`** with element id to which you want to add data.

**Full Source**

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm has-feedback <?php set_validation_style('Kota')?>">        
    <?php echo form_label('Kota / Kabupaten', 'kota', array('class' => 'control-label col-sm-2')) ?>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
       <?php
            $atribut_kota = 'class="form-control dropKota"';
            echo form_dropdown('Kota', $namaKota, $values->Kota, $atribut_kota);
            set_validation_icon('Kota');
        ?>
    </div>
    <?php if (form_error('Kota')) : ?>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3">
            <?php echo form_error('Kota', '<span class="help-block">', '</span>');?>
        </div>
    <?php endif ?>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropKota").select2({
                placeholder: "Pilih Kota"
            });
            $(".dropProv").on("change", function(){
                var idProv = $(this).val();
                var baseUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>program/administrasi/registrasi/ajax_get_kota/'+idProv;
                var kota = [];
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl,
                    data: kota,
                    dataType: "JSON",
                    success: function(datas){
                        var s= document.getElementById('<Element Id>');
                        s.eampty();
                        $.each(datas, function(index, el) {
                            s.options[index]= new Option(index, el);
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found the solution after asking here and there, so here's the solution:

**JS and select2 script**:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".dropProv").on("change", function(){
                var idProv = $(this).val();
                var baseUrl = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>program/administrasi/registrasi/ajax_get_kota/'+idProv;
                var kota = [];
                $.ajax({
                    url: baseUrl,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(datas){
                        //since select2 need a specific format u need to do this
                        var kota = $.map(datas, function (obj) {
                            obj.id = obj.id || obj.id_kab; // replace id_kab with your identifier
                            obj.text = obj.text || obj.nama // replace nama with your identifier
                            return obj;
                        });
                        $(".dropKota").select2({ //change dropKota into your element
                            placeholder: "Pilih Kota",
                            data: kota
                        });
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```